# What is a good way to get rid of fire ants in Florida?

Tags: pest-control, pests, ants

I unfortunately have huge 3 feet across and larger of fire ant nests in the yard.  I have tried Ortho Orthene and Spectracide but they aren't getting all the ants.  They just pack up and move over five or ten feet.

Comment: Do any of the answers [here](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3434/how-are-fire-ants-removed-without-endangering-vegetation-nearby) answer your question?

Comment: Not sure, some of that may work.  It looks like bait should be broadcast over a wide area and then go back and treat any individual nests that appear.  I was hoping for some people to jump in with their own experiences.